# Returning 204 response using Jersey Restful webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am using Jersey RESTful webservices.

This response object results in a HTTP response with status code 204:

```
return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
```

But I get the following content in SOAP UI:

```
<data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>
```

But i dont get any 204 in response. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the response code is not in the response body, it 
is in the response header. It looks something like this.

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

This is the so-called status line of an HTTP response.

Comment: Peter, then above response body is expected result right? Thanks!

Comment: @user755806 I think so, yes.

Comment: What should i do if i need to send the response in body
? Thanks!